# Is there a general term encompassing primary, intermediate, and secondary education?

Tags: terminology

Is there a general term encompassing the primary, intermediate, and secondary school levels? Perhaps pre-university or pre-college, maybe even prep school. However, the last of these, as I saw on [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/preparatory-school), refers rather to private and parochial schools. I would like to use it as an adjective.

Comment: Which is it that you're after??

Comment: @HotLicks When we say university, it can be interpreted as all four years of college. Can we do something similar with the three divisions of pre-college schooling.

Comment: Do you mean "primary, intermediate, and secondary" or "primary, secondary, and ternary"????

Comment: @HotLicks No, I am referring to the lower, middle, and upper schools divisions, the three divisions of schooling before university.

Comment: Then get your question and title to agree on that.

Comment: @HotLicks Oh, sorry. I didn’t even notice that.

Answer (score 0):

collectively called **K-12**  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%E2%80%9312)

> In the U.S.and other countries, generally there are three stages:
>   elementary school (K–5th/6th grade), middle school (6th/7th–8th
>   grades) and high school (9th–12th grades). 
>   [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Education_in_the_United_States)

Comment: Yes, but how can we refer to all of them collectively.

Comment: @majormaki public schooling

Comment: @majormaki yes i was editing  they are called K1-12,  'K thru 12' or even 'k to 12'.